# Particle hair dont follow mesh in animation

Tags: particles, hair

i have animated mesh with hair particle system. When I render any single frame along all animation so all looks good. But when I want render animation hair don't follow mesh..
Any idea why? Blender 3.0.1
edit: when i bake dynamics it also looks good, but i don't want dynamics..

Comment: maybe move the Armature modifier above the ParticleSystem modifier?

Comment: I don't have armature.. Hair mesh is Child of another armature bone..